# DAX Help : Filter on Full Weeks Only

Tags: powerbi, calendar, dax, powerquery, weekday

I have an odd request to report data in PowerBI on days in the previous month that are part of a full Sunday-Saturday week.

For example, February 2023 would only show data from the 5th to the 25th:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qldSK.png)

Days falling outside of those complete week cycles are to be omitted completely.

I have a datedim table with all the usuals, year/month/weeknum/weekbegindate/weekenddate/etc., but not sure how to go about putting this all together in PowerBI.

The data will be used in a matrix to show the average of instances occurring per day of the week for the previous month (example: total instances occurring on Sunday divided by the number of full Sun-Sat weeks in that month):
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGeki.png)

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated, I am stuck, stuck. Thanks!

What I've tried:

DaysOfWeek =
COUNTX (
FILTER ( 'Date'; EARLIER ( 'Date'[YearWeek] ) = 'Date'[YearWeek] );
'Date'[YearWeek]
)

Afterwards I created my max-week logic (max week where DaysOfWeek = 7), however this method includes days rolling over from the previous month- which I want to exclude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PQ, do the following.

1. Add Week of Month
2. Add month

[image]

3. Group as follows:

[image]

4. Remove redundant columns, expand the table again and add a new column as follows

[image]

5. You end up with a table as follows.

[image]

Use the Custom column as part of your filter in DAX whenever you need to see full weeks only

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}}),
    #"Inserted Week of Month" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Week of Month", each Date.WeekOfMonth([Date]), Int64.Type),
    #"Inserted Month" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Week of Month", "Month", each Date.Month([Date]), Int64.Type),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Inserted Month", {"Month", "Week of Month"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}, {"All", each _, type table [Date=nullable date, Week of Month=number, Month=number]}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Month", "Week of Month"}),
    #"Expanded All" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "All", {"Date"}, {"Date"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded All", "Custom", each if [Count] = 7 then "full" else "partial")
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

Comment: I had to add year to my grouping but this worked perfectly! thanks so much!!!!